# Possible meta-informations in R/exams

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I discover the very useful R/exams package, as well as its very complete documentation.

Unless I'm mistaken, I didn't find a place providing an exhaustive list of meta-informations that can be included at the end of a Rmd question. I'm particularly interested in the meta-informations in the context of a moodle export. I know that it is possible to define a section or a sub-section, or to request the upload of a document, for example. But what are all the other possibilities?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

| Tag | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `extype` | Specification of the type of exercise (required): `num` for questions with a numeric answer, `mchoice` for questions with multiple-choice answers, `schoice` for questions with single-choice answers (i.e., multiple-choice with exactly one correct solution), `string` for questions with a text answer, or `cloze` (i.e., combinations of the above). |
| `exname` | Short name/description (to be used for printing within R). |
| `extitle` | Pretty longer title (for Moodle). |
| `exsection` | Section of the exercise (for Moodle, with slashes for subsections as in a URL). |
| `exversion` | Version of the exercise. |
| `exsolution` | Correct solution (required). It must contain a numeric solution for `num`, a string of zeros/ones for `mchoice`/`schoice`, or a character string of `string`. For `cloze` a combination of these can be specified, e.g., `exsolution: 1.23|001|glm`. |
| `extol` | Tolerance for `num` solutions or a vector of tolerances (expanded if necessary) for `cloze` solutions. If unspecified the tolerance is 0. |
| `exclozetype` | List of types for the elements of a cloze exercise, e.g., `exclozetype: num|schoice|string` for the example above. |
| `exstringtype` | Type(s) of answer format for `string` exercises. The default is `string` but can also be `essay` (text editor) and/or `file` (upload menu). |
| `expoints` | Points for (fully) correct solution. Default is 1. |
| `exshuffle` | Logical or numeric indicating if/how to shuffle `schoice`/`mchoice` answers. |
| `exmaxchars` | Maximum number of characters in string answers (for QTI). |
| `exextra[]` | Additional metainformation to be read and stored, e.g., for new custom interfaces. The default storage type is character, e.g., `exextra[myinfo]: 1.23` yields a metainformation element `myinfo` of `"1.23"`. The type can also be numeric or logical, e.g., `exextra[myinfo,logical]: FALSE|FALSE|TRUE`. |

**Notes:**

- You are right that this is not easy to find. It is shown in Table 2 of the `vignette("exams2", package = "exams")` (also published in the *Journal of Statistical Software*). I plan to write a blog post about it when version 2.4-0 is released to CRAN.
- The table above also includes a couple of newer tags, added after the journal publication.
- In `exextra` you can include any custom information you wish, e.g., for storing meta-information you need for a custom `exams2xyz()` interface or for evaluating results.
- In `exams2moodle()` we support a couple of Moodle-specific `exextra` options, namely some detailed formatting of "essay" type questions. All supported options can be found in the [essayreg](https://www.R-exams.org/templates/essayreg/) exercise template.
- Additionally, it's possible to set the `numwidth` and `stringwidth` arguments from `?exams2moodle` also via `exextra` options. See the [fourfold2](https://www.R-exams.org/templates/fourfold2/) exercise template for a worked example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, this is really useful.
I am also looking for all the options available via the exextra command.
For example, I learned about the possibility of requesting the upload of a document with this example: https://www.r-exams.org/assets/posts/2017-08-14-essayreg//essayreg.Rmd

Are there any other useful tips? I admit that this may be a moodle specific question rather than the R/exams package. But having all the useful options in one place would be very useful to many people I think. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "all options": all supported by R/exams' `exams2moodle()` or all supported in Moodle XML? The latter is documented in https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Questions. But not all of these details are supported by R/exams: We rather focus on providing a simple standardized vocabulary that covers the most important options. Having said that, we have implemented a couple of Moodle-specific details, specifically for `essayreg` and `fourfold2`. I have refined my answer regarding these two points. Let me know if you have any remaining questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can see a list in `?read_metainfo` or in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exams/exams.pdf), `read_exercise`:

> read_metainfo returns a list with the following elements